# How to show hided Layout on progress bar click?

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I am using `ListView`, and I have a list of progressbars. When I click on one progressbar, then it shows the hidden Layout. But my problem is that when I click on another progress bar then it is not hiding previous Layout.
And I want that when I scroll the ListView then the showing Layout(which was hided before) must not be hide.

How can I implement it ?

```
public void onProgressClick(View view) {
     if(rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
       rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
       rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will break when the list is scrolled. But answering your question exactly, here is a solution.

```
private View lastItem;
public void onProgressClick(View view) {
    if(lastItem != null) {
        lastItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastItem = rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear;
    }
    else {
        rowItem.mSecretBoxLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lastItem = null;
    }
}
```

**EXTRA**
If you do not want it to break upon scrolling (and you did not find a way to fix this scrolling bug), you can save a boolean array of the same size of your data to save whether a certain view is visible or not and use this data in your `getView` function.

Comment: It is same as I want...:-)